# Can I refer json which is written in Swagger 2.0 from a Json which is written in OpenApi 3.0

Tags: json, swagger, swagger-2.0, swagger-codegen, openapi

New to Swagger and openApi.
I am trying to use openapi: 3.0.0. And I am using **OpenAPI 3.0 parser**
I am creating one file in openApi 3.0 and I have one existing file which is in swagger 2.0.
So I have to point/refer the file which is in swagger 2.0 from the file which is in openApi 3.0. 
And it is giving me error while doing it. 
So question is :
**Is it possible to refer file which is written with swagger 2.0 and refer it in file which is in openApi 3.0?** 
If yes then how?

Eg : TestSwagger.json in 2.0

```
    {
  "swagger": "2.0",
  "info": {
    "version": "1",
    "title": "testSwagger"
  },
  "definitions": {
    "TestSwagger" : {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "abc" : {
          "type": "string"
        }}}}}
```

Eg: TestOpenApi.json in 3.0

```
    {
      "openapi": "3.0.0",
      "info": {
        "version": "1",
        "title": "TestOpenApi"
      },
    "components" :{
        "schemas": {
          "TestOpenApi": {
            "properties": {
              "testSwagger": {
                "$ref": "TestSwagger.json#/definitions/TestSwagger"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
   }
```

Comment: *"And it is giving me error while doing it."* - what error? Which version of Codegen do you use and how do you run it (e.g. from Swagger Editor, from command line, etc.)

Comment: By the way, both specs need `"paths": {}` to be valid. `paths` is a required keyword.

Comment: So I do have Path in openApi3.0 file as it has request and response both. I just didn't put it here because I was trying to make it simple. But I dont have **paths** in **testSwagger** which is existing and working good in current project. Codegen version is 3.0.0 as it supports OpenApi 3. And I am using swagger plugin and maven.